# How to get rid of "finalize the string" box when typing in another language?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages, ime

I'm using Windows 10 to type in English and Japanese and I'm using the Japanese Windows 10 IME.

When I type in Japanese but not inside a textbox (e.g. in File Explorer if I just press a key without being in the middle of renaming a folder or anything).

I get this annoying box:

[image]

When I'm in Japanese input mode:

[image]

And it interferes with keypresses (hotkeys/shortcuts/etc.)

How can I get rid of this box? Nothing I've read elsewhere (older Stack Exchange posts, Reddit and even YouTube) works.

Comment: By the way, I still don't have a solution, but one very specific workaround that works for me is (since I'm typesetting, so there's moments when I'm working inside text boxes, and moments when I'm not and I want to use hotkeys etc.), I removed the Win10 Japanese IME, installed the Google Japanese IME, and it still doesn't fix things, but it allows me to use alt+` to have it on あ mode inside text boxes and A mode outside of text boxes within the same app, which wasn't possible with Win10 IME, so that is a workaround for my particular use case.